# how can i get multiple values in one line from scanf

Tags: c

i need to get multiple values work with them  then put them in an array (15 value)
I want to put all the values in a single line then take them one by one in a for

```
for(i=0;i< SIZEARRAY; i++)
{
        scanf("%d",&d);

    arr[i] = d;
    if(a < length(arr[i]))
    {
        a = length(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

and this is a picture of how this should look

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cecji.png

Comment: you have not posted the image. check it out

Comment: What happens at the moment if you put all the values on a single line separated by spaces? `scanf("%d",&d)` shouldn't care if you separate the values by spaces or newlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the scanf inside a loop and directly input into the array

```
for (size_t index = 0; index < SIZEARRAY; index++) {
    if (scanf("%d", arr + index) != 1) /* error */;
    // arr + index is the same as &arr[index]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < ARRSIZE; i++) {
    if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1) { /*error */ }
    /* ok, now process me */ }
}
```

Comment: I've taken both comments into account.. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your posted image,try this:

```
for(i=0;i< SIZEARRAY; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    //do whatever you need
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",arr[i]);` → `scanf("%d", &arr[i]);`

Comment: You either need `scanf("%d", &arr[i]);` or you need `scanf("%d", arr + i);`

Comment: @MASh: either use (`array + index`) or (`&array[index]`) *or (`index + array`) or (`&index[array]`)*

Comment: No. `arr[i]` gives the *value* (an `int`) stored in the `i`th index of `arr`. `%d` in the `scanf` expects an `int*`, the address of the variable to be stored.

Comment: @WeatherVane, wait, let me check.

Comment: You are right. My mistake. Thanks to all for your concern.